# Android: can you use an AlertDialog to clear data so it isn't corrupted after starting an email activity?

Tags: java, android, email

I have an Android app that emails some data. I also have button that fires an AlertDialog confirmation box that clears the same data.

The normal flow of the app is: fill data into pdf file->send email with pdf attachment->clear data on button press and repeat.

My question is this: is it humanly possible for a user to clear their data before the email is sent (so the data would all be blank)? I don't want my users sending blank emails because of a bug. The reason I'm asking this question is because I first had the data being cleared after the email activity was fired (this is a no-no) and was sending blank data. I've tried looking for a way to use StartActivityForResult() on the email activity so I can just destroy the data when the activity finished, but it doesn't look like this is possible. I think doing it with a confirm box is safe because the email activity should be finished, but I just want to be absolutely sure this is safe.

Comment: Do you want to clear the data from your previous mail or you want your users not to send blank mails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android devices can behave very different, one from another.  You could have slowness in your mail activity, or you could have your device to suddenly decide to clean up memory and make every thing slow slow slow for a moment.  If you are relying on timing in hoping that some other process or thread is completed before you delete something, you are playing with fire.

I think a better approach would be to start your e-mail activity for result, like CapDroid did in this answer:

**Send Mail:**

```
int EMAIL = 101;

Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.setType("text/html");

emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,new String[]{});
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_BCC,new String[]{});
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, pngUri);
startActivityForResult(emailIntent,EMAIL);
```

**Sending Result:**

```
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(requestCode==EMAIL)
            {
                if(requestCode==EMAIL && resultCode==Activity.RESULT_OK)    
                {
                                if(myFile.exists())
                                    myFile.delete();  
                    Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Mail sent.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else if (requestCode==EMAIL && resultCode==Activity.RESULT_CANCELED)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Mail canceled.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else 
                {
                    Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }   
        }
```

Comment: @HaIR Thanks! I'll do it this way.